# Profiling VS2008 C++ project, which is using static linking library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling, static-linking

i'm working on a mixed C/C++ project. Actually there are 5 pure C projects (compiled as .dll) and 1 C++ project (compiled as .dll) which is linking to an external static library (.lib + .pdb files).

VS2008 project has disabled "Enable just my code by default".

The debugging works perfectly: it's possible to see the source code of the C++ project, following methods and calls of the static library.

The problem is profiling: i can profile all projects, except the C++ one, which is linking to the static library. VS gives me VSP2701 Error, saying my .dll library "could not be found when looking for symbol information."

Someone knows how can i fix it ?

Comment: Sometimes people just want to profile so they can see some measurements. If the reason you want to profile is so that you can figure out how to make it run faster, you might want to check out *[this PDF slide show](https://sourceforge.net/projects/randompausedemo/files/)*.